# jquery css - fixed menu jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have some code as follows:
https://jsfiddle.net/k77986kL/

The idea is there is a header (containing images, text and various other things), and below that is a nav menu. My goal is to have the nav menu start beneath the header when the page first loads, but when the user scrolls down and the menu hits the top of the screen, it will stay there until the user scrolls back up

As you can see from the fiddle, the behaviour I'm getting is correct but theres a slight jumpiness to it. When you scroll down to the moment where the nav menu hits the top, the content suddenly jumps down. And when you scroll up the page, the content jumps again. It doesn't jump by a lot, but it jumps enough to be noticeable, especially if scrolling quickly

Looking at my jquery I cant see what might be causing this issue:

```
$(function () {
    var nav = $('nav');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                width: nav.width()
            });
            isFixed = true;
        } else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'relative'
            });
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
}

);
```

This is all lifted from my main project files, so there may be some css elements in there that are required for the demo itself, but I kept the CSS for those selectors intact just in case they may be causing this issue

Comment: It works fine for me. No jumpyness.

Comment: strange. I thought maybe it was my computer but I just tried on another windows machine and it still jumps. mostly tested in chrome, but its especially bad in IE

Comment: to be clear: the jumping only happens once the black nav menu hits the top of the page (i.e. all of the orange header section has been scrolled past)

Comment: I think you should look at .Clone(). The idea is that when the menu hits the top of the page, you clone it, and the clone floats down the page. When you reach the top again the clone is removed. Here's an old fiddle of mine that demonstrates cloning. I know it's not 100% what you want, but I thought it might set you on the right path [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KfxQg/)

Comment: Personally I think your eyes are playing tricks on you, it is kind of a weird effect, the focus changes mid-scroll. Regarding `Clone()` depending on the size of the DOM you are cloning the method can take some time. I would change CSS properties any day.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be an optical illusion. When using the scroll bar you can scroll slowly down to the point where the black nav reaches the top, and then even with the smallest amount of scrollbar scroll the nav bar jumps to cover 2 whole lines of the main text. Whereas, normally the smallest amount of scroll barely scrolls to cover half a line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you set `position: fixed`, the `nav` is out of the flow of the page, leaving free the space it occupied. Thus the content goes up to fill that space. The opposite happens when the `nav` becomes `position: relative`.

To fix that I simply set a `margin-top` to the `header` element that fill the space occupied by the `nav`, and I remove it when it is not needed.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/k77986kL/2/)

Here is the complete code:

```
$(function () {
    var nav = $('nav');
    var header = $('header');  // get header element
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                width: nav.width()
            });
            header.css('marginTop', nav.height()); // set margin-top
            isFixed = true;
        } else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'relative'
            });
            header.css('marginTop', 0); // remove margin-top
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
}

);
```